# Проблема с выводом текста на русском из MySQL(избранный случай)

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, utf-8

**Все необходимые меры соблюдены**: 
1) .php файлы в блокноте имеют кодировку UTF-8 без BOM 
2) БД, таблица, поля таблицы имеют кодировку utf8_general_ci 
3) В meta-тэге указан charset="UTF-8" 
4) В php-скриптах писал header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
Однако проблема с выводом русского текста из БД сохраняется. Что еще может быть не соблюдено? Впервые такой особенный случай.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может попробовать поставить кодировку общения с БД как UTF-8? `SET CHARSET utf8`

Comment: Выполнен запрос `SET NAMES utf8`, сразу после установки соединения с базой данных? Дело в том, что MySQL по умолчанию считает, что вы будете общаться с ней с использованием кодировки latin1 и осуществляется перекодирование.